# Can anyone please explain me this if Statement? What does this ! sign at the begining of if statement stands for?

Tags: conditional

Can anyone please have a look at this if statement and explain me what this ! at the beginning of if statement stands for? Isn't that means not? but that doesn't make sense here .

```
<apex:outputText value="{!IF(ISBLANK(pli.Print__c), '$0', '$') + 
      TEXT( ROUND((pli.Lift__c + (pli.revenue__c * (pli.Tax__c/100))) * (pli.Tax2__c/100),2)) }" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The syntactic convention of `{! ... }` is SFDC syntax meaning evaluate the contents as an SFDC formula, merging in values (like `pli.Print__c`) from the controller.

SFDC will evaluate all references to controller variables within a single `{!..}` without you needing to add extra `!` in front of each controller variable - note this is a common mistake.

For example:
If you have two controller variables `foo__c` and `bar__c` and wish to sum their values in a single outputText field, you would code:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!myObject__c.foo__c + myObject__c.bar__c}"/>
```

You would not code:

```
<apex:outputText value="{!myObject__c.foo__c} + {!myObject__c.bar__c}}"/>
```

However, sometimes you need to mix controller variables with CSS as in:

```
<apex:outputText>
    <span class="fooClass">{!myObject__c.foo__c}</span>
    <span class="constantClass"> is not a </span>
    <span class="barClass">{!myObject__c.bar__c}</span>
</apex:outputText>
```

Here, each controller variable is segregated out in its own merge field expression

Again, the purpose of the `{!..}` syntax is to have SFDC evaluate an expression using the richness of the [SFDC formula language](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_variables_functions.htm) before rendering the page.

From the doc:

> Use functions to transform data from records, perform calculations, or
>   to provide values for Visualforce attributes.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response crop1645 . So does this statement below menas the same? 
<apex:column headerValue="Date" value="{!sml.Date__c}" />

I am talking about this ! sign at value part?

Comment: Ricky - yes -- the SFDC formula in this use case is simply the value of controller field `sml.Date__c`.  `sml` is an iterator variable specified somewhat higher in your VF page (pageBlockTable, dataTable, repeat) that is iterating over a collection of records. So, `sml.date__c` is the value of a given row's `Date__c` field

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. One last question please. 
so if I want to calculate revenue on the same page (ex.   revenue - (LiftCost+OtherCost)) should Is this correct? <apex:outputText value="(sml.revenue__c - (sml.Lift_Cost__c+sml.Other_Cost__C)) / > or do I need to use ! before each SML? 

sorry if it is very basic question. I am fairly new to this.

Comment: I updated the answer with more detail